# Show there is a real number $c$, such that for any continuous $f$, $f'(x) =cx$ for some $x$ in $(0,1)$

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

Here is the full problem statement.
Show that there is a unique real number $c$ such that for any function $f$ that is differentiable on $[0, 1]$ and that takes the values $f (0) = 0$ and $f (1) = 1$ there is some point $x \in (0,1)$ (depending on the function $f\;$) such that $f'(x) = cx$.

I think the correct value of $c$ is $2$, by considering $f(x) = x^2$, and can also use that function to prove uniqueness of $c$. I’m having a hard time proving that any $f$ must have such a point. I think it will be an application of MVT, but would appreciate a hint.
Cheers!

Comment: Apply Rolle's theorem to $$g(x)=f(x)-x^2$$ there exist some $x \in (0,1)$ such that $g'(x)=0$. This means that $f'(x)=2x$.

Answer (score 1):

let's tryna see wha we get
$x^2$ is important function
the $f(x) -x^2$ is zero at the extremes
So derivative zero is what u want

Answer (score 0):

Let $g(x)=f(x)-x$, $g(0)=g(1)=0$ implies there exists $x_0$ such that $g'(x_0)=0$ implies $f'(x_0)=1$.